# Finding the distance between the two closest numbers in an array of n numbers. (Presorted Arrays)

Tags: loops, array-algorithms

The arrays are presorted making the algorithm θ(nlogn) [sorting+finding minimum distance], compared to bruteforce θ(n2). Both the codes does the same job but the first one shows time limit exceeded. I wonder what the error is. Any bug in the code?

*Code with while loop (time limit exceeded)*

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mindistance(int a[],int n)
{
    int i=1,arraymin=999,currentmin,current=a[0];

    while(i<n)
    {
        if(a[i]==current)
            i++;
        else
        {
            currentmin=a[i]-a[i-1];
            if(currentmin<arraymin)
            {
                arraymin=currentmin;
                current=a[i];
                i++;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("%d",arraymin);
}


int main(void)
{

    int a[]={4,34,56,77,99,424,754}; 
    mindistance(a,7);

    return 0;
}
```

*Code using for loop (works well)*

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mindistance(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,arraymin=999,currentmin,current=a[0],x,y;

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==current)
            continue;
        else
        {
            currentmin=a[i]-a[i-1];
            if(currentmin<arraymin)
            {
                arraymin=currentmin;
                current=a[i];

            }

        }
    }
    printf("%d",arraymin);
}


int main(void)
{

    int a[]={4,34,56,77,99,424,754};
    mindistance(a,7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i++` should always happen. So, in the while loop either do it as the first thing in the loop or the last thing in the loop. Don't do it in the if statements. Whatever, there is an else missing `if(currentmin<arraymin)` if you insist on doing it in the tests.?

Comment: This did work. General i++ statement after the if-else clause. But why wasn't it working earlier with seperate i++ increment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops are not identical. In the for loop i is increased in each iteration, while in the while loop i is increased only in some cases. An identical while loop would be:

```
while(i<n)
{
    if(a[i]==current)
        i++;
    else
    {
        currentmin=a[i]-a[i-1];
        if(currentmin<arraymin)
        {
            arraymin=currentmin;
            current=a[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand why we cannot increment i inside the if clause? Its just like any other variable right? or should it be incremented with matching if-else clause only?

Comment: You can. But in the while code you wrote you don't increment i in iterations where you enter the else clause but currentmin>=arraymin (therefore you are not entering the second if clause and i is not incremented). In the for loop you wrote i is increamented in every iteration (even if currentmin>=arraymin).

Comment: Yeah did notice that..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting caught in an infinite loop because you aren't setting currents value every iteration.

Comment: Worked with general i++ statement after the if-else clause. But why wasn't it working earlier with seperate i++ increment ?